# how to take a value main method and use it in different method

Tags: java

Basically, I want to use to put a value into main and set it up so I can use the word/words entered into main so I can use the code.

```
public static  String L33TLanguageSupport(String s) {
    Scanner scan =new Scanner (s);
    char o = 0;
    char O=0;
    char e=0, E=0, a=0, A= 0;
    return s
        .replace(o, (char) 0)
        .replace(O,(char) 0)
        .replace(e, (char) 3)
        .replace(E,(char) 3)
        .replace(a, (char)4)
        .replace(A, (char)4);
}

public static void main (String[] arg) {
    System.out.println(L33TLanguageSupport("cow life" ));
}
```

Comment: Please do not add tags that are unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the user input using `Scanner` in your desired method, then retrieve the result into a variable and send it to another method.

Adapted from your posted code:

```
public static  String L33TLanguageSupport(String s) {
    //remove this from here
    //Scanner scan =new Scanner (s);
    //do what it must do...
}

public static void main (String[] arg) {
    //System.out.println(L33TLanguageSupport("cow life" ));
    //creating the scanner to read user input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //showing a nice message to user
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    //reading the user input (the whole line until user press Enter key)
    String input = scanner.readLine();
    //applying the method to user input
    String output = L33TLanguageSupport(input);
    //showing to user the result of the processing
    System.out.println("Result: " + output);
    //closing the scanner resources
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: i tryed this and it just printed out what i put in

Comment: Then looks like you have a problem in your `L33TLanguageSupport` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the same by doing `java main cow life` and then passing in those arguments to the `L33tLanguagesupport` object concat'd together.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String arg : args) sb.append(arg).append(" ");
    System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
}
```